# Which one is better way in terms of performance to use IPC listener in electron?

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc, event-listener

I have a lot of IPC listeners (**more than 30**) on my electron application, but I wonder which one is better in terms of performance.

**The first solution (Implement IPC listener as many as it needed):**

```js
ipcMain.on('appLanguageChange', (event, data) => {
    //do something with data
})
ipcMain.on('current-patient-ask', (event, data) => {
    //do something with data
})

ipcMain.on('patient-set', (event, data) => {
    //do something with data
})

//Still need many listeners below..
```

**The second solution (Using Switch and only implementing one IPC listener):**

```js
    ipcMain.on('data-flow', (event, topic, data) => {
        switch (topic) {
            case "appLanguageChange":
                //do something with data

            case "current-patient-ask":
                //do something with data

            case "patient-set":
                //do something with data
                break;
             //Still need many cases below..
    })
```

Currently, I am using the second solution, is it a good approach? Because I am aware that some people could get a warning that too many IPC listeners have already implemented.  How many maximum IPC listeners could be implemented if there is a limitation? It would be better if someone could explain the pros and cons of the two methods. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Electron uses Node.js underneath and Electron's IPC is based on Node events, any limits would be imposed by Node and
not Electron (unless otherwise defined by electron, which I don't believe it is).

As per the latest Node.js Event documentation, once you have more than 10 listeners per event a warning will be emitted.
The
thing to note here is "more than 10 listeners **per event**".

> See this Node link for more
> information: [events.defaultMaxListeners](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/events.html#eventsdefaultmaxlisteners)

As each `ipcMain.on('channelName', () => { ... })` is a listener for, in this example, an event named `channelName`, you
would need more than quantity 10 of the `ipcMain.on('eventName', () => { ... })` methods in your code before a warning
is throw.

As all your `ipcMain` methods seem to be for different event names, there is no operational benefit between either of
your solutions.

That said, your first solution would be the preferred solution, allowing you to place your individual `ipcMain` calls
into their "associated files". EG: `appLangaugeChange` events would be coded within your `language` scripts whilst
your any `patient` events would be coded within your `patient` scripts. This will keep your code seperated, logical,
expandable and simple to debug.

Additionally, as your project grows, a particular section of code can listen for an event emitted by an
unrelated section of code, if needed. EG: Submitting some new information on a form may update more than one panel in
your main window, or update multiple child-windows, all at the same time.

On the discussion of "performance", if your events were firing every couple of milliseconds then one would want to look
at micro-optimisation. But based on the event names, this is not the case, so any solution would work. If anything,
it would probably be more based on your preferred coding style.

As a closing note, consider the `ipcMain` method and its associated Electron methods only as an extension of Node
events. They are not special or magical, but only a simple observer design pattern. This way, you will write better,
more modular code.